# Spectral radius of a normal operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I am stuck in intermediate step of a proof.

Let $||A^2|| = ||A||^2$ = $||A^*A||$

Then how to show this?

$||{A^2}^n||^2$ = $||{{A^*}^2}^n {A^2}^n||$ = ${{||A^*A||}^2}^n$.

Here $A^*$ denotes the Hilbert-Adjoint Operator.

Comment: "normal opera" full marks for the short title.

Comment: Happened by mistake

Answer (score 2):

Let's call 1) $\|A^2\|=\|A\|^2$, and 2) $\|A\|^2=\|A^*A\|$.

Then $\|A^{2^n}\|^2=\|(A^{2^n})^*A^{2^n}\|$ by 2).

$\|(A^{2^n})^*A^{2^n}\|=\|A^{*^{2^n}}A^{2^n}\|$, since $(A^k)^*=(A^*)^k$ for every $k$.

$\|A^{*^{2^n}}A^{2^n}\|=\|(A^{*}A)^{2^n}\|=\|\big((A^{*}A)^{2^{n-1}}\big)^2\|=\|(A^{*}A)^{2^{n-1}}\|^2$ by 1) and $A$ being normal.
Now you proceed by induction until you get to $\|A^{*^{2^n}}A^{2^n}\|=\|A^*A\|^{2^n}$.

Comment: 2 holds for $A$. How to show it holds for ${A^2}^n$?

Comment: I suppose the first set of equalities hold for normal operators in general. If $A$ is normal, then $A^{2^n}$ is normal too. Can you see why?

Comment: Wait..Second holds for every bounded L.O..right?

Comment: Yes, but the thing is I don't know what results you have already.  If you know 2) holds for every bounded linear operator, and $A$ is bounded, $A`{2^n}$ (use induction) is bounded so 2) holds for it. If you are operating in a finite dimensional space it's even easier, because every linear operator is bounded.

Comment: Does this answer your question?